# Timestamptz, same point in time but different representation for same query with 'set local time zone'

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone, node-postgres, pg-promise

I am trying to build my web app that will store the data on a PostgreSQL database server running on some location on Earth and will have users connecting from other locations, so probably different timezones and offsets than my servers.

I need to show the dates and times of the actions like, posts created, posts edited, comments submitted, etc. according to the each connecting user. This is just like the StackExchange. However I am running into problems of timezones and offsets as described as follows:

Everything seems working correct in my *pgAdmin3 SQL Editor*. When I write the query below in *pgAdmin3 SQL Editor* with `set local time zone 'Europe/Oslo'`, for example, I get both the `posts` and `tags` table `created_at` fields correct with `+2` offset in the output. In the output row, the `created_at` field of `posts` table is `2016-08-29 19:15:53.758+02` and for same row `created_at` for `tags` table is `2016-08-29T19:15:53.758+02:00`.

**However**, when I put it in a *route function* in my *Nodejs* *Express.js* server with *pg-promise* as the connection lib, I only get the `tags` table `created_at` field correct with the time in `Oslo` with timezone offset appended as expected, I get `created_at` field of the `posts` table in `UTC` not as expected.

All *timestamps* are defined as `timestamp(3) with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as shown below. Also, without the setting `set local time zone`, I get the same behaviour, for first table I get `UTC` time, for the latter I get timestamp with offset of server appended.

Does not the `set local time zone` directive bind all the query? What is the missing point in my approach?

an example query I use:

```
select
    q.*, -- created_at timestamp (with time zone) is one of those columns
    u.name as author,
    u.reputation,
    case when count(t.*)=0 then '[]' e json_agg(t.*) end as tags
from posts q

-- authors
join users u
on q.author_id = u.id

-- tags
left join post_has_tag p_h_t
on q.id = p_h_t.post_id
left join tags t
on p_h_t.tag_id = t.id

where q.post_type = 'question'
group by q.id, u.id;
```

An example express.js route function:

```
trialRoutes.get('/x', function (req, res) {
    db.query(
        `
        --begin;
        SET LOCAL TIME ZONE 'Europe/Oslo';
        SELECT
            q.*, -- created_at timestamp (with time zone) is already in here
            u.name AS author,
            u.reputation,
            CASE WHEN count(t.*)=0 THEN '[]' ELSE json_agg(t.*) END as tags
        FROM posts q

        -- authors
        JOIN users u
        ON q.author_id = u.id

        -- tags
        left join post_has_tag p_h_t
        on q.id = p_h_t.post_id
        left join tags t
        on p_h_t.tag_id = t.id

        WHERE q.post_type = 'question'
        group by q.id, u.id;
        --commit;
        `
    )
        .then(function (data) {
            res.json(data)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("/login, database quesry error.", error);
        });
})
```

The result I get from *Express.js* http server with *pg-promise*. Note the different timestamps that actually should point same point in UTC, which is correctly done, and representation which is not correctly done:

```
[
  {
    "id": "7",
    "created_at": "2016-08-29T21:02:04.153Z", // same point in time, different representation
    "title": "AAAAAAAAAAA",
    "text": "aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa",
    "post_url": "AAAAAAAAAAA",
    "score": 0,
    "author_id": 1,
    "parent_post_id": null,
    "post_type": "question",
    "is_accepted": false,
    "acceptor_id": null,
    "timezone": "2016-08-29T20:02:04.153Z",
    "author": "Faruk",
    "reputation": 0,
    "tags": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "created_at": "2016-08-29T23:02:04.153+02:00", // same point in time, different representation
        "label": "physics",
        "description": null,
        "category": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "created_at": "2016-08-29T17:24:10.151Z",
    "title": "Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL",
    "text": "Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL",
    "post_url": "Ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-Rails-and-PostgreSQL",
    "score": 0,
    "author_id": 2,
    "parent_post_id": null,
    "post_type": "question",
    "is_accepted": false,
    "acceptor_id": null,
    "timezone": "2016-08-29T16:24:10.151Z",
    "author": "Selçuk",
    "reputation": 0,
    "tags": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "created_at": "2016-08-29T19:24:10.151+02:00",
        "label": "sql",
        "description": null,
        "category": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The definition of the `posts` and `tags` tables used here:

```
-- questions and answers
CREATE TABLE posts
(
  id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at timestamp(3) with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

  title character varying(100),
  text text,
  post_url character varying(100),

  score integer DEFAULT 0,
  author_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES users (id),
  parent_post_id integer REFERENCES posts (id),
  post_type varchar(30),

  is_accepted boolean DEFAULT FALSE,
  acceptor_id integer REFERENCES users (id) DEFAULT NULL
  --seen_by_parent_post_author boolean DEFAULT false

  --view_count
  --accepted_answer_id
  --answer_count
);

CREATE TABLE tags
(
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at timestamp(3) with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    label character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    description character varying(200),
    category character varying(50)
);
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are setting the time zone via pg-promise?

Comment: I have added a route function on my server.

Comment: It could be that [pg-types](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types) still doesn't handle all the situations properly. You can set your own parser and that way try to debug it. Parser can be set via `pgp.pg.types.setTypeParser(id, handler)`.

Comment: I will then open an issue in the respective repository? You can do it also, if you think you have a good understanding of the library, which seems very probable.